# EF Core - save file to database without reading to RAM first

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using **.NET Core 3.1** and **PostgreSQL** database. I have the following database model:

```
public partial class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Also, I have a **large** file (>500MB) saved on the disk at `TempFiles/file.data`. If I want to save the attachment to the database, I can do the following:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
    Content = File.ReadAllBytes("TempFiles/file.data")
};

_dbContext.Attachment.Add(attachment);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This works perfectly fine. The problem is, that the file is loaded into RAM first and only then saved into the database. If multiple users call this method at the same time, server can run out of RAM memory.

How can I avoid reading the file to RAM? Instead, I want to save its content **directly to database**.

Comment: Frankly, an ORM probably isn't the tool you want in this scenario - they are usually oriented around in-memory models, so they don't really cater for this. In this scenario, you are going to have to do more work yourself, either using the SQL Server "filestream" support, or by using the BLOB append features in TSQL (and a loop over the input stream)

Comment: If you have a SQL Server you can create a View instead of returning data to c#.  Run query as cmd.ExecuteNonQuery.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You cannot stream into a SQL query/command. SQL is a string, and as such, the file data must be read completely in order to fully construct the SQL command that will then be sent to the database. Large files should not be stored in databases, particularly for reasons like this. Save it to the filesystem and simply store a file path in the database.